# How to select all records from one table that do not exist in particular year?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

the table looks like this

```
num  Year
 1 | 2014
 2 | 2014
 3 | 2014
 2 | 2015
 4 | 2015
 5 | 2015
 6 | 2015
```

I would like my query to return

```
 4 | 2014
 5 | 2014
 6 | 2014
 1 | 2015
 3 | 2015
```

from 1 to 6, the number that is not used in particular year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate the all the combinations and then take out the ones that exist:

```
select n.num, y.year
from (select distinct num from t) n cross join
     (select distinct year from t) y left join
     t
     on t.num = n.num and t.year = y.year
where t.num is null;
```

Note that `year` is a bad name for a column in SQL Server because it is the name of a function and a keyword (think `datepart()`).